# DataGridView - Focus and SelectAll in a cell

Tags: c#

Any number of answers on this site demonstrate selecting a specific cell in DataGridView.  The problem is, while the cell becomes active and can be set in edit mode, it does not respond in the same was as when it is clicked.  The cursor is placed in the cell, at the end of the text, which makes it easy to overlook.

When a cell is clicked, it is highlighted and all text is selected and ready for overtype. I want to emulate a click on the cell to get that kind of response.  That makes it more obvious to the user which cell is being edited.

Comment: what have you actually tried.. can you tell us what the properties of the DataGridView are set as in regards to allowing column / row editing..? do you have any `OnClick or OnDoubleClick` events setup..show us your code

Comment: This is not true. The result of clicking a selected cell and setting the current cell and calling beginedit(true) are the same. If you see something different you have messed up the DGV somehow. Only the position of the cursor may differ but where else but to the end should it go when using code??

Comment: I beg to differ - if you click in a cell or tab to it, the background color changes to show it is selected.  When you select it, that happens in some cases but not always.  In particular, I am trying to get the grid's DataError event emulate the click so that it is obvious to the user which cell is in error.